# tfs tools to handle concurrency in main and feature branches

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

In our org, we work on many feature branches under the same project.However we face many issues when merging code where people working in other branches don't know the changes made.Due to concurrency issues,sometimes it breaks in production. Can anyone recommend a tool for TFS similar to what sourcetree does for github?. We face many concurreny issues as there are many people working on the same project with many branches. We would like to notify use if any merges have been made in the main branch or the feature branch.

Comment: Why not protect the branches you typically build and release with branch policies and manage merges via pull requests?

Comment: This sort of thing has not been done. There are many developers working on many freature branches and they get deployed on out of cycle releases and the main problem faced is merging from the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

To get alert when there is a merge to main branch, you can create a Checkin Alert "A file is checked in under a specified path" to make "Server item" "Under" "$/*TeamProject*/*MainBranch*". In this way, when there is checkin on MainBranch or FeatureBranch, an alert will be sent out.

By the way, to use Feature isolation branching strategy, the considerations should be include:

- Each feature branch should be a full child branch of the main branch.
- Keep the life of your feature development short, and merge with
  main frequently.
- Feature branches should build and run Build Verification Tests
  the same way as main.
- Merge frequently from main to feature branches if changes are
  happening directly on main.
- Merge from feature to main based on some objective team criteria.

You can get more information about merge and branch at website:
https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases